# How do I refer to another typescript type in comments/JSDoc?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm familiar with Javadoc. In Javadoc, [you can place a link that refers to the Javadoc placed on another type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915992/how-to-reference-a-method-in-javadoc) like so:

```
/**
 * some java thingy. see this other java thingy too {@link OtherThingy}
 */
public class Thingy { /*...*/ }

/**
 * some other java thingy. see the first java thingy too {@link Thingy}
 */
public class OtherThingy{ /*...*/ }
```

Can I do the same in typescript's flavor of JSDoc? I know that I can use markdown in the comments and I can place web links but that's not exactly what I'm going for.

Also, any references to JSDoc/typescript documentation tools would be very helpful :)

**Edit**: Per the answers below, this is a feature of JSDoc but doesn't seem to be included in VSCode. Is there an valid syntax in VSCode?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### Yes, you can use `@link`

You can use `{@link OtherThingy}` in docs, and it works in VS Code since 2021. If you want an inline reference, just use that.

#### Details and alternatives

With VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020), you might also consider another tag:

> ### [Initial support for JSDoc `@see` tags](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/7354aa9d3dabe4f458ddf5c6c09608d1d165ba05/release-notes/v1_52.md#typescript-41)
>
> JSDoc `@see` tags let you reference other functions and classes in your JSDoc comments.
>
> The example below shows crash function referencing the WrappedError class from another file:
>
> ```js
> // @filename: somewhere.ts
> export class WrappedError extends Error { ... }
>
> // @filename: ace.ts
> import { WrappedError } from './somewhere'
>
> /**
> * @see {WrappedError}
> */
> function crash(kind) {
>    throw new WrappedError(kind);
> }
> ```
>
> VS Code will now include basic @see references while performing renames.
>
> You can also run go to definition on the `@see` tag's content and @see tags will also show up in the list of references.
>
> We plan to continue improving support for @see tags in future releases.

As Mark notes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306153/how-do-i-refer-to-another-typescript-type-in-comments-jsdoc/65206472?noredirect=1#comment118187327_65206472):

- [PR 119358](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/119358) adds support for JSDoc link tags in VSCode 1.55 (March 2021)
- VSCode 1.57 (May 2021) [adds `@link` support](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/1735dfae164f4593912182843fd04cfb97c9f69a/release-notes/v1_57.md#jsdoc-link-support)

> ### JSDoc `@link` support
>
> We now support [JSDoc `@link` tags](https://jsdoc.app/tags-inline-link.html) in JavaScript and TypeScript comments.
>
> These let you create clickable links to a symbol in your documentation:
>
> [image: Navigating code using JSDoc @link tags]
>
> JSDoc `@link` tags are written as: `{@link symbolName}`.
>
> You can also optionally specify text to be render in place of the symbol name: `{@link class.property Alt text}`.
>
> `@link` is supported in hovers, suggestions, and signature help.
> We have also updated `vscode.d.ts` to use `@link`.

---

Note: [cachius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11760058/cachius) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306153/how-do-i-refer-to-another-typescript-type-in-comments-jsdoc/65206472#comment134337571_65206472):

> ```
> import { MyClassName } from "path/to/MyClassName";
> ```
>
> If `MyClassName` is not already imported, adding `@see MyClassName` in the JSDoc would only show `any` on hover and doesn't allow ctrl + clickthrough to declaration/usages.
>
> Importing it allows that, even if the only mention is in the JSDoc.
> This is useful when a module/class refers to some other logically, but without using it directly.
>
> Unused imports might trigger `eslint` warnings though, which I'd silence in this case with:
>
> ```
> // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
> ```

---

To that effect, [Daniel Steigerwald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233902/daniel-steigerwald) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306153/how-do-i-refer-to-another-typescript-type-in-comments-jsdoc/65206472#comment136722684_65206472)

> **The imported type must be actually used**.
> **Otherwise, JSDoc will not process**.

And:

> Another more serious issue is that destructuring removes any JSDoc part containing `@`, making it effectively useless.
> That's why I have to replace all `@example` with Markdown, e.g. `### Example ts ...`

---

[Eric Haynes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1057157/eric-haynes) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306153/how-do-i-refer-to-another-typescript-type-in-comments-jsdoc/65206472#comment135810886_65206472):

> Consider using instead:
>
> ```
> import type { MyClassName } from 'path/to/MyClassName';
> ```
>
> The type import will be elided at compile time, rather than adding an actual import in the compiled JavaScript.
> (or `import { type MyClassName, OtherThing }` if you already have an import for something else on that path)

---

> This seems to be the correct solution using `import { type Foo }`.
> However, I get `no-unused-vars eslint` errors on the import, although it doesn't give me the `typescript Foo   is declared but its value is never read.` warning.
> Is there a way around this or is it an eslint bug?

While TypeScript understands that the import is used for type information and will remove it in the transpiled JavaScript (hence no TypeScript error), ESLint's default rules do not recognize type-only imports as being "used". Consequently, ESLint reports them as unused variables.

You can try and adjust your ESLint configuration to ignore unused vars that are only imported for types. That can be done by modifying the `no-unused-vars` rule in your `.eslintrc` configuration file, specifically using the `ignoreRestSiblings` and `argsIgnorePattern` options to exclude type imports:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": ["error", { "ignoreRestSiblings": true, "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }]
  }
}
```

But that involves "tweaking" to specifically target type imports without inadvertently ignoring genuinely unused variables.

Another approach is to use the [`eslint-plugin-import` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import), which provides more granular control over import-related linting issues. That plugin includes a rule `import/no-unused-modules`, which can be configured to allow type-only imports. Make sure to install the plugin and configure it in your `.eslintrc`:

```json
{
  "plugins": ["import"],
  "rules": {
    "import/no-unused-modules": [1, { "ignoreExports": ["path/to/your/typescript/files/**/*.ts"] }]
  }
}
```

You would specify paths and patterns that match your project's structure: it is more work upfront, but can lead to more precise control over linting behaviors.

If the issue only occurs in a few places and you prefer not to adjust global ESLint settings, you can disable the ESLint rule inline for specific imports:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import { type Foo } from './foo';
```

If you are using the `@typescript-eslint` plugin (which is recommended for TypeScript projects), it provides a more TypeScript-aware version of the `no-unused-vars` rule. Make sure your ESLint is configured to use this rule instead of the base ESLint version:

```json
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": "off", // Turn off ESLint's version
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error"] // Use TypeScript ESLint version
  }
}
```

That rule is better at understanding TypeScript's type-only imports and should not flag them as unused.

Comment: better answer for 2020. nice

Comment: @link support in vscode: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_57.md#jsdoc-link-support

Comment: @Mark Thank you.  I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: `import { MyClassName } from "path/to/MyClassName";` if the symbol cannot be resolved. Please eslint with `// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` if needed.

Comment: @cachius Is that an error message you see? Or something you had to apply?

Comment: If MyClassName is not already imported, adding `@see MyClassName` in the JSDoc would only show `any` on hover and doesn't allow `ctrl + click`through to declaration/usages. Importing it allows that, even if the only mention is in the JSDoc. This is useful when a module/class refers to some other logically, but without using it directly. Unused imports might trigger eslint warnings though, which I'd silence in this case.

Comment: Consider using `import type { MyClassName } from 'path/to/MyClassName'` instead. The type import will be elided at compile time, rather than adding an actual import in the compiled JavaScript. (or `import { type MyClassName, OtherThing }` if you already have an import for something else at that path)

Comment: The imported type must be actually used. Otherwise, JSDoc will not process it. It took me an hour to figure out why some types work while others don't.

Comment: @DanielSteigerwald Good catch, thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Another more serious issue is that destructuring removes any JSDoc part containing @, making it effectively useless. That's why I have to replace all @example with Markdown, e.g. ### Example ```ts ... ```.

Comment: @DanielSteigerwald Thank you. I have edited the answer to also include your second comment.

Comment: This seems to be the correct solution using `import { type Foo }`. However, I get `no-unused-vars` eslint errors on the import, although it doesn't give me the typescript `Foo 
 is declared but its value is never read.` warning. Is there a way around this or is it an eslint bug?

Comment: Wow, thanks @VonC. Edit: I couldn't get it to work the way I'd like using a mix of different `plugin:@typescript-eslint`, `import/no-unused-modules`, or `import/no-unassigned-import` configs. I'm sure it's possible somehow.

Comment: @JamesHeazlewood Is your ESLint configured to use the TypeScript parser? Maybe an `eslint your-file.ts --debug` could help.

Answer (score 34):

You sure can, though your mileage may vary.

1: [A use of `@link` in Selenium-Webdriver's TypeScript typing file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/selenium-webdriver/index.d.ts#L344)

> ```
> /**
>  * Converts a level name or value to a {@link logging.Level} value.
>  * If the name/value is not recognized, {@link logging.Level.ALL}
>  * will be returned.
>  * @param {(number|string)} nameOrValue The log level name, or value, to
>  *     convert .
>  * @return {!logging.Level} The converted level.
>  */
> function getLevel(nameOrValue: string | number): Level;
> ```

2: [Docs about `@link` in JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-inline-link.html)

> The following example shows all of the ways to provide link text for the {@link} tag:
> Providing link text
>
> ```
> /**
>  * See {@link MyClass} and [MyClass's foo property]{@link MyClass#foo}.
>  * Also, check out {@link http://www.google.com|Google} and
>  * {@link https://github.com GitHub}.
>  */
> function myFunction() {}
> ```
>
> By default, the example above produces output similar to the following:
> Output for {@link} tags
>
> ```
> See <a href="MyClass.html">MyClass</a> and <a 
> href="MyClass.html#foo">MyClass's foo
> property</a>. Also, check out <a 
> href="http://www.google.com">Google</a> and
> <a href="https://github.com">GitHub</a>.
> ```

Comment: I probably should've just tried javadoc's syntax huh?

Comment: I just started using [typedoc](http://typedoc.org) and it supports `@link`. Your answer deserves the check

Answer (score 14):

VS Code treats `{@link}` as a comment, so it doesn't get any special parsing (it's just displayed exactly as you typed it). There's currently [an open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35524) to fix this, however.

Comment: See comment above re `@link` supprot.

Comment: Meanwhile you can use `[myFile.ts](./myFile.ts)` for VS Code.