# A legend or glossary that links to parts of my code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to do this? I've got some heavy scripts with a lot of lines in my code. Is there a way to put "quick links" to parts of my code in some kind of legend or glossary? I'm using Visual Studio Code. It would save a lot of scrolling time.

I've had a look but I can't find anything. Maybe there's an add-on?

edit: I am coding in python within Visual Studio Code. But I would hope that this translates to any code. It doesn't feel like it should be a code specific feature. It would just be jumping to a line somewhere in the file.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I add links in comments to a code block in Visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760491/can-i-add-links-in-comments-to-a-code-block-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Could you please clarify: What are you writing, which language? You can probably put your parts into different files. I am not aware of quick links in any way tbh.

Comment: I was going to mark this as off-topic, but it seems actually to be a duplicate. Skip over the  Accepted Answer and [view this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72100939/1270789) that describes the exact feature you need, although only for Java/TypeScript.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I don't think any of those links answer my question. I checked through the entire threads. I would want to hyperlink to a line in the code. I'm coding in python but if the feature exists I would imagine it wouldn't matter. I just want to go to a designated line.

Comment: Does the `Outline` view help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a legend to jump to some Part of your current code file you can use the extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links) (better name would be **Related Links** but historically it was only for HTML files)

Look at [Example 4](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links#example-4-table-of-content) how you can make a TOC using special comment lines.